# Showing background though navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to copy this site as part of a bootstrap learning course. 
(https://trickyicky84.000webhostapp.com/). The HTML has nav followed by a section element (with class intro) and there is a background image applied to the section element.

You can see that the nav has a background of dark in View Port <768 but becomes transparent >768 and the background image applied to. The intro section seems to show through in the nav. I am unable to figure which code is making the nav transparent and more importantly how does the background image applied to a section, apply to the nav element.

I am assuming it is this:

```
@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: none;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

I have tried similar code in my own version (making background:transparent for the navbar) but it seems to be taking the background :0 0 style from Bootstrap giving it a grey like color. I have not studied CSS transitions yet and I am unsure if this is being done using the transitions in the original site. My site is at https://trickyicky83.000webhostapp.com/ .

The complete CSS for the version that is working:

```
@import "vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "vendors/font-awesome/font-awesome.less";

@primary: #26a5d3;
@dark: #333333;
@light: #f4f4f4;

html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:@dark;
    background-color:@light;
}

// Typography

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

p{
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

a{
    color:@primary;

}

a:hover,a:focus{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: darken(@primary, 20%);
}


// Navigation

 .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: @dark;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-custom a {
    color: @light;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: @light;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: none;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: none;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: @dark;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
}


// Landing Page

.intro{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:100px 0;
    text-align:center;
    color:@light;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color:@dark;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}

.intro-body{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.brand-heading{
    font-size:40px;
}

.intro-text{
    font-size:18px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .intro{
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
    }

    .brand-heading{
        font-size:100px !important;
    }

    .intro-text{
        font-size:25px;
    }
}
```

This is my version which is not working :

```
@import "vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.less";

@primary: #26a5d3;
@dark: #333333;
@light: #f4f4f4;

body {
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: @light;
    color:@dark;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

// typography 

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:0 0 30px;
    letter-spacing:1px;

}

p {
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

// Navigation

 .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     background-color:@dark;   

}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-weight:700;
    color:@light;
} 

.navbar .nav li a {
    color:@light;
}

.navbar .nav li a:hover {
    color:@light;
}
.navbar .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar .nav li a:hover,
.navbar .nav li a:focus,
.navbar .nav li.active {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar {
        padding:20px 0 ;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;    
    }
}

//intro 

.intro {
    display:table;
    padding:100px 0;
    width:100%;
    color:@light;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
    background-color:@dark;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
.intro-body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.intro h1 {
    font-size:40px;
}

.intro p {
    font-size:18px;
} 

@media(min-width:767px) { 
    .intro h1 {
        font-size:100px !important;     
    }
    .intro p {
        font-size:25px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your CSS code something like this. And also, remove the `margin-top: 50px` property from `body`

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```